# jquery not working in published site but working in development environment

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I using jquery to change style of some element of my asp.net page as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string scrp3 = "$(document).ready(function () {if ($('#MainContent_chbkCooperation_1').is(':checked')) {if (!$('#MainContent_chbkCooperation_0').is(':checked')) {$('.pajooheshVal').hide();}}});";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), ClientID, scrp3, true);
    }
```

in my local test this style works but when its published on server its not working , and styles remain the same.

## Note:

I have multiple updatepanel in my page and using ms-ajax.
How do i hide my elements in every full and asyncpostbacks of page ?

Comment: What does `console.log(jQuery)` gives you in production? and errors?

Comment: I`m not sure how to use that command but when i put that in console and test the page something like this showd up ,  Uncaught Error: `selector` option must be specified when initializing tooltip on the window.document object!

Comment: Yes in console. And it should give you `function(a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}` which means jQuery object exists and library loaded successfuly. Check in network tab if you have a 404 for the library also.

Comment: yes i`m getting function(a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} but in the next line i also get undefined , and in network tab all thing are fine and all status ar 200 OK

Comment: it is okey about the undefined, and thankfully you have no problem with loading the library.  +1

Comment: The error message sounds like you are using a tooltip plugin, maybe from bootstrap, and you initialize it on the document element instead of a class selector, so it requires further configuration. Try to find the place where this happens and check the documentation of the tooltip plugin for correct initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i work around through this problem as below from cliend side :

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded);

function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        if ($('#MainContent_chbkCooperation_1').is(":checked")) {
            if (!$('#MainContent_chbkCooperation_0').is(":checked")) {
                $('.pajooheshVal').hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

this helped me to run jQuery on every asyncpostback of page .
for full postback i used jquery it self.